# Execute a SQL String and insert result into table

Tags: sql-server, sp-executesql

I have a table

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE(QueryIndex smallint, FieldValue nvarchar(50))
```

QueryIndex is a loop counter, it will get value from @QueryIndex.
FieldValue will get value from another SQL String. For some reason, I need to execute SQL string dynamically.

```
SET @SQL = "SELECT " + @FieldName + " FROM MyView"
            + " WHERE Condition1='" + @Value1 + "'"
            + " AND Condition2=" + CONVERT(nvarchar(12),@Value2)
```

Now I try to insert data into @Results

```
NSERT INTO @Results(QueryIndex, FieldValue)
SELECT @QueryIndex, EXEC (@SQL)
```

No surprise, this code won't work. Please provide me solution to insert data into my table. Any methods will be worth trying.
The result in table should like this:

```
QueryIndex   FieldName
  1            First
  2            Second
  3            Third
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine the retrieval of `@QueryIndex` with the select then you can simply

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + cast(@QueryIndex as varchar(16)) + ',' + @FieldName + ...
INSERT INTO @Results(QueryIndex, FieldValue)
   EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should create the structure of the containing table - before !

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp  // or @tbl... doesnt really matter...
      ( 
        ...
      ) 

    INSERT INTO #tmp  -- if we use exec we  must have the pre-Structure of the table
    EXEC (@sql)
```

now  , Do waht ever you want to do with `#tmp`....

Comment: `#tmp` or `@tbl` may matter - `@tmp` couldn't always be the target of insert / exec (though I honestly forget when that changed).

Comment: @Royi Namir thanks for suggesting. But I think it is not solution for my case. As Alex's solution, I just want to insert 2 values at the same time. There's not much different between using temp table and using var table here :)